# Unable to populate a Cart Session with Product item

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, dependency-injection, .net-6.0

Building out a new .net6 site but the switch from using HttpContext.Current.Session is the end of me right now.

I have a Cart in my .net 6 site where in a view I'm triggering an AddToBasket action, this action creates a new instance of 'BasketItem' and should be adding that item to my 'Cart' Session.  In debug I can see the Session is being created, I can see the new 'BasketItem' is being created but I cannot get the BasketItem in to add to the Session.

In my Startup.cs:

ConfigureServices -

```
            services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
            services.AddOptions();
            services.AddHttpClient();
            services.AddControllers();
            services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
            services.AddSession(options => {
                options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60);
            });
```

Configure -

```
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseUmbraco()
                .WithMiddleware(u =>
                {
                    u.UseBackOffice();
                    u.UseWebsite();                    
                })
                .WithEndpoints(u =>
                {
                    u.UseInstallerEndpoints();
                    u.UseBackOfficeEndpoints();
                    u.UseWebsiteEndpoints();
                    
                });
            app.UseCookiePolicy();
            app.UseSession();
        }
```

BasketItem model -

```
    public class BasketItem
    {
        public IPublishedContent ProductPage { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
        public bool IsOptionalExtra { get; set; }
        public bool IsMainProduct { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public IPublishedContent ExtraMainProductPage { get; set; }

    }
```

BasketController - AddToBasket

```
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult ProductPageAddToBasket(decimal productPrice)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                return CurrentUmbracoPage();

            bool addedToCart;

            if (productPrice > 0)
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(productPrice.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)))
                {
                    var productPriceValue = productPrice;
                    addedToCart = GetCart().AddProduct(CurrentPage, 1, productPriceValue);
                }
                else
                {
                    addedToCart = GetCart().AddProduct(CurrentPage, 1, 1);
                }

                // create some temp data to use to show if the product has been added successfully or not
                if (addedToCart)
                {
                    TempData["success"] = "You have successfully added the product to the basket...";
                }
                else
                {
                    TempData["failure"] = "Opps, There was an error adding the product your basket...";
                }
            }
            return RedirectToCurrentUmbracoPage();
        }
```

In my public class Cart which is in a separate controller -

```
private List<BasketItem> lineCollection = new List<BasketItem>();

            public bool AddProduct(IPublishedContent productPage, int quantity, decimal price)
            {

                BasketItem line = lineCollection.FirstOrDefault(product => product.ProductPage.Id == productPage.Id);
                var exsistingProduct = false;

                if (line == null)
                {
                    lineCollection.Add(new BasketItem
                    {
                        ProductPage = productPage,
                        Quantity = quantity,
                        Price = price,
                        IsOptionalExtra = false,
                        IsMainProduct = true,
                        Description = "Quantity : " + quantity + " @ : £ " + price.ToString("c"),
                        ExtraMainProductPage = null
                    });

                    // for main products check and add an non optional extras set on the product
                    CheckAndAddExtras(productPage, quantity, price, exsistingProduct);
                    return true;
                }
                else if (line.Quantity > 0)
                {
                    line.Quantity += quantity;
                    line.Description = "Quantity : " + line.Quantity + " @ : £ " + price.ToString("c");

                    exsistingProduct = true;
                    // for main products check and add an non optional extras set on the product
                    CheckAndAddExtras(productPage, quantity, price, exsistingProduct);
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
```

and in my Basket Surface Controller

```
        public Cart GetCart()
        {
            Cart cart = SessionHelper.GetObjectsession<Cart>(HttpContext.Session, "Cart");

            if (SessionHelper.GetObjectsession<Cart>(HttpContext.Session, "Cart") == null)
            {
                cart = new Cart();
                SessionHelper.SetObjectsession(HttpContext.Session, "Cart", cart);
            }
            return cart;
        }
```

SessionHelper -

```
    public static class SessionHelper
    {
        public static void SetObjectsession(this ISession session, string key, object value)
        {
            session.SetString(key, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value));
        }
        public static Cart GetObjectsession<Cart>(this ISession session, string key)
        {
            var value = session.GetString(key);
            return value == null ? default(Cart) : JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Cart>(value);
        }
    }
```

In my view I'm injecting IHttpContextAccessor and trying to get the Cart session in 'basketCart, which at the moment is returning null.

```
CartController.Cart basketCart = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.GetObjectsession<CartController.Cart>("Cart");
```

Hope I've given enough detail there, hopefully someone will spot something, just a final thing when the product is added to the cart I should be redirect to the /basket page with a product line shown but obviously it's empty at the moment.

I've implemented the SessionHelper and tried different iterations of this to get the BasketItem added to the Cart Session but in both debug and in my view it always returns null.  Not seeing any errors in build but clearly missing a step here.

Comment: Have you check the sessionid if you were trying with the same session?

Comment: @RuikaiFeng running through debug actually and the session id's are not the same, on my Product page, the session is indeed different to the GetCart method session Id.  I'll go back and try and at least get these using the same session and update this post, thanks again, appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Just to close this one off, we've refactored the solution to use a list item in the SessionHelper, I could not get the session populated from my cart model.

```
        public static void Set<T>(this ISession session, string key, T value)
    {
        session.SetString(key, System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(value));
    }


    public static T Get<T>(this ISession session, string key)
    {
        var value = session.GetString(key);
        return value == null ? default : System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(value);
    }
```

So we get the cart session using -

```
List<BasketItem> basketCart = SessionHelper.Get<List<BasketItem>>(httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session, "Cart");
```